# Does being Cloned reset the failure chance on longevity potions?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, potions

Let's assume a mage has been drinking longevity potions for a while, and after finally coming across a clone scroll, he decides to kick back to his youth.

Does the chance of failure for the potions reset, or does it stay the same?

Answer (score 9):

*I would say **YES**, but it **depends.***

***Potion of Longevity***

> When you drink this potion, your physical age is reduced by 1d6 + 6
>   years, to a minimum of 13 years. Each time you subsequently drink a
>   potion of longevity there is a 10 percent cumulative chance that you
>   instead age by 1d6 + 6 years.

***Clone***

> This spell grows an inert duplicate of a living creature as a
>   safeguard against death. This clone forms inside a sealed vessel and
>   grows to full size and maturity after 120 days; you can also choose to
>   have the clone be a younger version of the same creature. It remains
>   inert and endures indefinitely, as long as its vessel remains
>   undisturbed. At any time after the clone matures, if the original
>   creature dies, its soul transfers to the clone, provided that the soul
>   is free and willing to return. The clone is physically identical to
>   the original and has the same personality, memories, and abilities,
>   but none of the original's equipment. The original creature's physical
>   remains, if they still exist, become inert and can't thereafter be
>   restored to life, since the creature's soul is elsewhere.

Seeing as Clone creates a duplicate creature, it would be safe to say that this creature is a completely different being. So, this creature would not retain the penalty of the Potion of Longevity as it is not "you" as stated in both descriptions.

However, the Clone could be argued that it "IS" you once your soul enters its vessel. So, it may carry over the previous life's fail accumulation chance.

If I was the DM, I would say that the Potion of Longevity applies ***only to your BODY***, so even if you were to cast your soul into your duplicate, I would rule that the duplicate is not YOUR body in the sense of the body in which you drank the potion. ***My ruling would be that it WOULD reset the failure chance***.

But, if you use the clone scroll, you can reverse your age considerably to something very young, and you would retain ALL of the knowledge and personality your past soul carries over, meaning you can be the early age of 20 and have the life experience of a 500 year old elf. I'm assuming that your previous character has already used a Potion of Longevity since you are asking this, with the addition of the use of Clone, I would also assume that your character has reversed or CAN reverse a considerable amount of years. I believe, instead of worrying whether or not the potions would stack, you would possess a hefty amount of years to find someone who is capable of casting Clone on you again, or finding some other means to reverse your age. That is just a suggestion.

I'd also like to know what instance you are worried about reversing a character's age so badly as I've been playing my current session for quite a few months with only several weeks going by. If you are playing a game where there are timeframe jumps, perhaps your DM may allow that you've found someone who could cast this spell for you whilst that time has passed. OR, if you are playing a game that has passed THAT much time, I'd say that you should just enjoy the ride that you've already taken, and let your character train an apprentice and finally rest.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The fact that the potion only effects your **physical** age would lead me to agree with you. +1

Comment: To propose a viable **fictional** scenario where the aforementioned mechanics would clash: this  is why the Q has the story of a mage that only comes across the clone spell AFTER drinking several potions of longevity. I agree with the last two paragraphs that this is a less than optimal path for someone with allegedly genius intellect and probably would follow as you say on this answer.

Comment: It's always fun to try to think of scenarios that might twist certain mechanics of the game, but sometimes, there is such a conventional solution that you forget all about it because it seems too dull. Also, what if the DM ruled that there was NO ONE in the world that could cast the clone spell on you, while completely unrealistic in, in the right setting, it could be possible, meaning this method of age reversing may one day have to be utilized by someone.